# What is the type of a pointer to a variable-length array in C?

Tags: c, pointers, language-lawyer, variable-length-array

Here's a short C program that prompts the user for a number, creates a variable-length array of ints of that size, and then uses pointer arithmetic to step over the elements that were allocated:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    /* Read a size from the user; inhibits compiler optimizations. */
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n); // Yes, I should error-check. :-)

    /* We now have a VLA. */
    int arr[n];

    /* What is the type of &arr? */
    void* ptr = (&arr) + 1;

    /* Seems like this skipped over things properly... */
    printf("%p\n", arr);
    printf("%p\n", ptr);
}
```

You can try this [on ideone](https://ideone.com/qCNgnh) if you'd like. The output suggests that the line

```
void* ptr = (&arr) + 1;
```

takes the address of `arr` and, in a size-aware way, steps over all `n` of the elements in the variable-length array.

If this were not a variable-length array, I'd be completely comfortable with how this works. The compiler would know the type of `arr` (it would be `int (*) [K]` for some constant `K`), so when we add one to `&arr` it could skip over the right number of bytes.

It's clear how, at runtime, we could evaluate `(&arr) + 1`. The compiler stashes the size of `arr` somewhere on the stack, and when we add one to `(&arr)` it knows to load that size in order to compute how many bytes to skip over.

However, what I don't know is what the language says the type of the expression `&arr` is. Is it assigned some static type that indicates it's a variable-length array (something like `int (*) [??]`)? Does the spec say "the type of the expression is `int (*) [K]`, where `K` is whatever size is assigned to the array at runtime?" Does the spec disallow taking the address of a variable-length array, and the compiler just happens to allow it?

Comment: Forming a pointer to a variable-length array is definitely allowed; among other things, VLAs of VLAs wouldn't work if you couldn't do that.

Comment: See the example at &sect;6.5.6 para 10

Comment: [The example rici is referring to.](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.6p10)

Comment: It will be a pointer to variable length array type. The `sizeof` operator evaluates the operand to determine the size of the variable length array object, so `+` must do the same thing. See C.2011 - 6.5.6/10.

Comment: Strictly speaking, I don't think the compiler is allowed to *re-evaluate* the expression which originally defined the size of the VLA, since the original expression may have side effects.

Comment: The decompiled code uses alloca and the following cast: int (*)[].

Comment: Oops, I take back my earlier comment.  gcc says:  ISO C90 forbids variable length array 'arr'.  But when speicyfing C99, it gives no warning.  So my guess is that this is allowed in C99.

Comment: Would it help if I posted the disassembled and decompiled code for this? I don't know how to explain it though

Comment: @savram My question is less about how that works - the mechanism is pretty clear to me - and more about how the C spec assigns types to the expressions here. I don’t think disassembling things would provide any extra insight.

Comment: I think the decompiled(not the disassembled) version helps, but if you say so I won't post it then.

Comment: @savram Seeing a single compiler’s disassembled output won’t tell us what the spec says about pointers to variable-length arrays. Ideally, I’d like some kind of reference to the C spec outlining what’s supposed to happen.

Comment: I said decompiled, not disassembled. The decompiled version is in C, and it's more rudimentary. It has this cast: int (*)[]. Anyway, ok then.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With a VLA, the `sizeof` operator is not a compile-time constant.  It is evaluated at run-time.  In your question, the type of `&arr` is `int (*)[n];` — a pointer to an array of `n` values of type `int`, where `n` is a run-time value.  Hence, as you note, `&arr + 1` (parentheses not needed except around parenthetical comments noting that the parentheses are not needed) is the start of the array after `arr` — the address is `sizeof(arr)` bytes beyond the value of `arr`.

You could print the size of `arr`; it would give you the appropriate size (`printf()` modifier `z`).  You could print the difference between `&arr + 1` and `arr` and you'd get the size as a `ptrdiff_t` (`printf()` modifier `t`).

Hence:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n;
    if (scanf("%d", &n) == 1)
    {
        int arr[n];

        void* ptr = (&arr) + 1;

        printf("%p\n", arr);
        printf("%p\n", ptr);
        printf("Size: %zu\n", sizeof(arr));
        printf("Diff: %td\n", ptr - (void *)arr);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And two sample runs (program name `vla59`):

```
$ vla59
23
0x7ffee8106410
0x7ffee810646c
Size: 92
Diff: 92
$ vla59
16
0x7ffeeace7420
0x7ffeeace7460
Size: 64
Diff: 64
$
```

No recompilation — but `sizeof()` is correct each time the program is run.  It is calculated at run-time.

Indeed, you can even use a loop with a different size each time:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n;
    while (printf("Size: ") > 0 && scanf("%d", &n) == 1  && n > 0)
    {
        int arr[n];

        void* ptr = (&arr) + 1;

        printf("Base: %p\n", arr);
        printf("Next: %p\n", ptr);
        printf("Size: %zu\n", sizeof(arr));
        printf("Diff: %td\n", ptr - (void *)arr);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Sample run of `vla11`:

```
$ vla11
Size: 23
Base: 0x7ffee3e55410
Next: 0x7ffee3e5546c
Size: 92
Diff: 92
Size: 16
Base: 0x7ffee3e55420
Next: 0x7ffee3e55460
Size: 64
Diff: 64
Size: 2234
Base: 0x7ffee3e53180
Next: 0x7ffee3e55468
Size: 8936
Diff: 8936
Size: -1
$
```

Comment: Yup. §6.5.3.4 The sizeof and _Alignof operators. (C11 n1570 draft)

Comment: Interesting. So the type is “an array of whatever size it ends up being.” That’s cool! I didn’t know that.